# PHP: Preg_Match, trying to return a certain number of characters ahead of match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to match a certain string - then return, lets say 3 characters before and after that string. How would I do that? Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('all.htm');
$regex = '/span/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);?>
<pre>
<?php var_dump($match);?>
</pre>
```

And that returns:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "span"
}
```

Comment: Can you embellish? What is an example string of something you will be trying to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will match up to 3 characters before and after a specified string (here is "span")

```
/(.{0,3})span(.{0,3})/
```

You can pick up the adjacent characters from the match array.